# JQuery is not defined in wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

im trying simply alert inside jquery but i get this error. "JQuery is not defined"
Here is my code
http://codepaste.net/uq9dey
What's wrong i didn't get...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `JQuery`. It should be `jQuery` (no capital `J`)